# Как добавить класс в body::before?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```
body{
  position: relative;    
}
body::before {    
    background-size: cover; 
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

И `css` код:

```
    body.grad1 { 
    background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px;    
    background-color: #12364a;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
}
```

Я добавляю этот класс при нажатии на див таким способом:

```
document.body.classList.add('img6');
```

но он добавляется в `body` и выглядит в итоге по-другому, а как добавить в `body::before`?

Comment: никак. В псевдо элементы нельзя добавлять хтмл атрибуты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. В псевдо элементы нельзя добавлять хтмл атрибуты. Как вариант, задать псевдо элемент для класса и менять класс элемента, вместе с чем будет задействован нужный псевдо-элемент.

```js
function changeClass(elem) {
  document.body.classList.toggle('grad1');
}
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;    
}
body::before {    
    background-size: cover; 
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
    z-index: -1;
}
body.grad1::before { 
    background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px;    
    background-color: #12364a;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id='elem' onclick='changeClass()'>Hello world!</div>
```